# Creating a Server for phone or sms

Tags: sms, windows-server-2008-r2, phone-call

This is my newest project which consists of making a Server for phone and sms. I would like to do something like google talk where one would be able to make calls and receive calls or even text through the internet.

I would than be able to connect a land line phone or even just a microphone and call my cellular and talk. Otherwise just sending a sms message through the internet to my cell would be awesome as well.

Any Reference or guides would be much appreciated.

Notes:

Yes I know there are websites that do these things. Not what I am asking.
I got a Windows Server 2008 r2 setup at home.
I think I am a decent programmer, enough to be able to program this if I have some clue what I should be searching for.
Do not tell me it is impossible, as not too long ago I saw usb hardware that allowed to make calls over the internet (I know it's more complicated than that but I want to have this knowledge)

Answer (score 1):

For the SMS part there is the SMSLib (http://smslib.org/), where you can use an attached phone to send and receive SMS.
You could provide a webinterface to write and read the SMS then of course, that would be the easier part.

For the calling I don't know, but it should be possible too. I know there are GSM chips for e.g. arduino but I guess it is very hard to reroute them to the application on the server. It *could* be possible with a short delay though.
Another option is to look into a **VOIP library**, e.g. Asterisk (http://www.asterisk.org).

Comment: VOIP is a past project. But the SMSLib i did see it but then there is no use for the server... as it forces you to use the phone sms ... it would just be an app or something... nothing really fun or useful

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're saying. You can attach the phone to the server and send SMS through the server (via SMSLib or AT-Commands). It's not an app on the phone. I have a webinterface myself where I can send SMS through the phone on my server at home. You would need an (old) phone of course, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: My problem would be to have a provider for the phone right ? Is this possible with a phone that isn't connected to any providers(AT&T, FIDO...).

Comment: Can you also provide me some links to where to read on this  more ?.

Comment: It must have a provider of course. You will not be able to send free sms

Answer (score 1):

For phone you have two options:

1. not buying hardware and use voip. You can use some voip to land line gateways. There are many ways for achieving that. The most "professional" would be buying did number: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/DID+Service+Providers. But there are other ways for example using skype api.
2. second option is connecting server to landline using special hardware - http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/FXO

Probably the funniest part would be writing webgui since writing PBX part could be little tricky. You should consider using Asterisk (free, Open Source) - Linux or 3CX (non-free)  - Windows.

Regarding sms:

1. You can use sms gateway i.e.: http://www.clickatell.com/
2. You can buy gsm modem to your server

Answer (score 1):

Okay, as others have already suggested, Asterisk is one the most obvious ways to go. Some time ago we created an online solution which allows most of the things that you have described, voip calling, dial plan generation, pbx, connection with landlines, sms sending, payments.

Tools used:
 - LAMP (linux, apache, mysql, php)
 - Asterisk
 - OpenSer (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSER)
 - 3rd party for SMS sending
 - 3rd party for billing.

Comment: Any documentation where I can read on how this is possible/made ?

Comment: you might want to explore: http://opensips.org/, https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Home As for SMS, as guys suggested clickatell is a good option.